# Me detecta composer 1 cuando estoy usando composer 2 en Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, composer

Al intentar hacer deploy en Heroku me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
 !     The following is the full output from the installation attempt:
 !     
 !     > You are using Composer 1 which is deprecated. You should upgrade to Composer 2, see https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
 !     > Loading repositories with available runtimes and extensions
 !     > Updating dependencies
 !     > Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
 !     > 
 !     >   Problem 1
 !     >     - The requested package composer-plugin-api could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
 !     >
```

No hay mucha información de como solucionar esto ¿De que otra forma mas debo de especificar que se esta usando composer 2? Todo fue instalado desde composer 2.

composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "App/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.4",
        "abraham/twitteroauth": "^3.2",
        "jenssegers/blade": "^1.4",
        "bramus/router": "^1.6",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.55",
        "phpfastcache/phpfastcache": "*",
        "php": ">=8.0"
    }
}
```

composer --version

```
Composer version 2.2.1 2021-12-22 22:21:31
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema fue la versión exacta de composer, heroku trabaja con la versión de composer 2.1.14 (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#installation-of-dependencies) y mi composer era la 2.2.1.

Lo arregle con lo siguiente:

Elimina composer.lock & vendor

```
composer self-update 2.1.14
```

```
composer install
```